# Recursive functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Please help me understand this recursive function...

```
var stack = Array;
function power(base, exponent){
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        stack[exponent-1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
        return stack[exponent-1];
    }
}
```

I dont understand what

```
stack[exponent-1]
```

is doing

Comment: shortest would be "base ^ exponent" :)

Comment: (To comment above: actually, `^` is exclusive or, not power.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did console log of stack[exponent-1] using

```
var stack = Array;
function power(base, exponent){
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        stack[exponent-1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
        console.log(stack[exponent-1]);return stack[exponent-1];
    }
}
```

O/P:

```
power(2,5)
2
4
8
16
32
```

So function class recursively until exponent become 0 (nth call), then it will start returning results

```
first it will return 1     (because exponent is 0)
        then returns 2 * 1 (return of n call)
              then   2 * 2 (return of n-1 call) 
              then   2 * 4 (return of n-2 call) and so on
```

Comment: Ohh, so it runs completely and then returns. I was wondering how it would be correct of it just kept returning! Thanks so much

Comment: when you call a function 1 and function 1 calls function 2 and function 2 called function 3, response will come first from function 3 then function 2 then function 1, its a stack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)

Answer (score 2):

Which one? It's called twice. But each time it's either getting the value that exists in the array at the index equal to the current value of `exponent-1` or setting that value.

It's just an array index and access.

Comment: @Sam Huh? Explain how to access values that are members of an array? That's all that it is doing. Let's say `exponent = 5`, so that call translates into `stack[4]`, accessing the fifth element of the array (array indexes start at 0). [Mozilla documentation for array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). They're both identical in nature, just one of them sets a value (the one with the =) and one of them gets a value.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is **stacking** the result of each power from the initial exponent to 0.

If you run `power(2, 3)`, the stack will, at some point, be:

```
stack[2] = 8
stack[1] = 4
stack[0] = 2
```

This really has nothing to do with the mathematic concept of power.

Comment: I think that would be the other way around. stack[0] being 2 and stack[2] being 8.

Comment: How does it return all of them at once? That's the part confusing me to make the stack array complete.

Comment: That's exactly my point. You shouldn't return that statement. It's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this version!

```
function pow(x,n)
{
     return n==0?1:n==1?x:n==2?x*x:pow(pow(x,(n-n%2)/2),2)*(n%2==0?1:x);
}
```

can get it shorter?

Comment: Is this an answer, or a question? If it's a question, please post it as such. If it's an answer, I can't see how it answers the question. You could post the question on [codereview.se] or [codegolf.se] (as a challenge), perhaps.